# Excel - Pick Unique Random Values from List, Replicate for 1000 Rows

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am looking for help in trying to pick 5 unique values from a specified list, have these appear in a row, then replicate this down 1000 rows.

[image]

How would I do something like this? Would I be able to use a function or create a macro for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this in C2:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,$A$2:$A$14/(COUNTIF($B2:B2,$A$2:$A$14)=0),RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNT($A$2:$A$14)-COLUMN(A:A)+1))
```

Copy across 5 columns and down 100.

[image]

Comment: Scott Craner if I could ever buy you a beer as a way of saying thank you, I would :) This works perfectly. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Just mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer

Comment: If you had the time to explain Scott I would also love to know how this works?

Comment: @WhatsTheAnswer Aggregate is just that an aggregation formula.  The `15` use the SMALL aspect.  The `6` ignores the errors, this is important as we will force some #div0 errors.  So what the third part does is create an array of the numbers and errors.  In the first column there are no errors just numbers, the second will introduce on error the third will intorduce two and so on.  These errors will happen where the values are already found in the columns preceding the current thus the `6` ignores them.  The Rand is what chooses randomly on whats left.

Comment: @WhatsTheAnswer The Count- Column subtracts one from the total count so we only randomly select a `k` value that falls in the array of numbers, without errors.

Comment: Close to getting it. Thanks for taking the time to explain - been trying to find ways to practice with aggregate but it's a tough one to grasp. Also, sorry about earlier confusion lulz

Comment: This is very elegant, I wish I had thought of it. Just to note (I think I am right in saying) the formula as it stands will not include the last item in the list, 0.9

Comment: @TomSharpe you are correct.  I have fixed the problem.